# Kill all WiFi connectivity processes

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, services

I have a laptop running Ubuntu 14.04, but I'm having WiFi connectivity issues. When I switch on the laptop, it can connect to WiFi with no problems, but after some time that the WiFi was on (connected or disconnected), the WiFi stops working. It shows that it is connected, but the internet connection doesn't work. If I disconnect and try to reconnect, it won't connect again to any WiFi (but Ethernet always works). I've tried to put it on airplane mode, disabling WiFi, killing wifi-manager, using a USB wireless adapter, but nothing short of rebooting works to get the WiFi back up.

I presume that the reason it works is because rebooting causes a specific service or program that is causing the issue to restart.

My question is, does anyone know how I can restart that WiFi connectivity service that is causing the issue without having to restart the whole computer?

**EDIT:**

The outputs of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` are:

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:b736]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be
```

Comment: Olease [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 Done. How does that command help?

Comment: You do not need to restart anything. Just fix the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

`sudo restart network-manager`

Response:

`network-manager start/running, process $your_pid`